# Rust cargo: how to use different features for a dep when a particular feature is enabled?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

For example I define 2 features without dependencies:

```
[features]
default = []
py2 = []
py3 = []
```

Based on selected feature (`--features py3`) I want to enable different features for a dependency (`cpython`):

```
[dependencies.cpython]
default-features = false
# features = ["python27-sys"]      I want to select this if py2 is enabled
features = ["python3-sys"]
optional = true
```

Can I do this? Or simply can I select features for a dependency from command line as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was discussed [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/633). One can do it with `/`.

```
[features]
default = []
py2 = ["cpython", "cpython/python27-sys"]
py3 = ["cpython", "cpython/python3-sys"]
unstable = []

[dependencies.cpython]
# git = "https://github.com/dgrunwald/rust-cpython.git"
default-features = false
optional = true
```

I've seen nothing about it in documentation or official pages.

Comment: Is there a way to  direct the default-features setup to be true or false based upon the enabled feature?